# Change Parameter Group of AWS RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to change the parameter group of an AWS RDS instance?

I've created a new parameter group. So now I have default and my new one.

In RDS Dashboard > Instances, on my instance under configuration details I see that default group is selected.

But don't see anywhere to edit the group on the instance. Clicking the group under configuration details loads the parameter group page.

This entire article never actually mentions how to change the group on the instance. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To change anything like that you click on the RDS instance and then select "Modify". In the Modify screen you can select a different parameter group.

From @bitavoc's reply -
If the dropdown doesn't let you select a parameter group recently created, check that both the parameter group and the RDS instance use the same major version of the engine.

Comment: perfect thanks, it is in drop down menu Instance Actions > Modify

Comment: if the dropdown doesn't let you select a parameter group recently created, check that both the parameter group and the RDS instance use the same major version of the engine.

Comment: The tip from @bithavoc should be included in the AA. It's easy to miss this during the creation of the CG.

Answer (score 2):

See the "[Modifying a DB Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html)" section of the docs.

[image]

That page also goes over how to modify the db instance via the CLI, e.g.

```
aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier <your instance name> --db-parameter-group-name <your PG name>
```

See the [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-instance.html) for the other options you can specify in the `modify-db-instance` command.

Comment: The CLI part of the answer was just what I was look for!